# How does OrcJIT or MCJIT implement function-level parallel compilation on a huge module?

Tags: llvm, jit, mcjit

I have a huge module with about 800 functions in it. Now I want to use MCJIT or OrcJIT for multi-thread compilation. I plan to use 8 worker threads and compile 100 functions per thread.

But I found that MCJIT cannot achieve parallel compilation, while OrcJIT can only perform parallel compilation at the Module level.

So can OrcJIT achieve function-level parallel compilation? Can you give some sample code?

I have generally browsed the OrcJIT code and found nothing related to function-level parallel compilation.